# Check linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let A,B,C be vector space over f. If r,s€f and set {A,B,rA+SB+C} is linear dependent, then what about {A,B,C} ? 
Is it linear dependent, independent or null set.
I was thinking of linear dependent. Am I right ? Can anyone explain me!!

Comment: Write down your definition a linear dependant set. Apply it to  {A,B,rA+sB+C}. Then apply it to {A,B,C}. Can you deduce the second part from the first ?

Comment: Do you mean $A$, $B$ and $C$ are elements of a vector space?

Comment: A,B,C are itself vector space's

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\{A,B, rA+sB+C\}$ is dependent. Then we can find constants $c_1, c_2, c_3$ (at least one of which is nonzero) such that
$$c_1A+c_2B+c_3(rA+sB+C)=0$$
Rearranging this gives us
$$(c_1+c_3r)A+(c_2+c_3s)B+c_3C=0$$
If all three of the above coefficients are zero, then $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$, a contradiction. Therefore, we have found a nontrivial linear combination of $A,B,$ and $C$ equal to zero, and so $\{A,B,C\}$ is dependent.